# Number of monomial terms

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to calculate the number of monomial of a certain degree in a polynomial of $n$ variable of degree $m$(for example 6 variable that multiplied toghether for a monomial of degree 6)

Reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928712/number-of-elements-in-polynomial-of-degree-n-and-m-variables) answer I'm a little confused

he wrote:
$$ \binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1} = \binom{n + m - 1}{n}$$

where $n$ is the degree and $m$ is the degree of the terms that we want to calculate.

I tried to apply that formula to a small case with 2 variables.
So I have this:
$$
1 + x +y+xy+x^2+y^2
$$

using the formula to calculate the number of monomials of degree 2 I get:
$$
\binom{3}{2}=\binom{3}{1} = \frac{3!}{1!(3-1)!} = 3
$$
with n = 2 and m = 2 
If I try to calculate the number of monomials of degree 1 (so the linear terms) I get:
$$
\binom{2}{0}=\binom{2}{2} = 1
$$
but I have $x$ and $y$ so the result should be 2.
Is the formula not general and only works to calculate monomial of degree $>1$?

EDIT:
I was using the example in the link to calculate the monomial of degree 2 in a polynomial with 3 variables(like in the example of the link).
With $n = 3$ and $m=2$ i get 4 as result but the terms are 6:
$$
xy,xz,yz,x^2,y^2,z^2
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the wrong bottom number into the binomial coefficient. For the linear case, $m=2$ and $n=1$, so we get $\binom{2+1-1}1=\binom21=2$ as expected.

Comment: oh I see I've inverted the variables for degree of the polinomial with the degree of the monomial terms($n$ and $m$).

Comment: @malloc Please, in all cases, check your variables. $m$ is the number of variables, $n$ is the target degree.